# Windows 10 Booting from Wrong Drive

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

I have an installation of Windows 10 on a 512GB SSD and cloned the installation to a 1TB SSD using AOMEI Backupper (standard). Both drives are formatted as GPT. In the BIOS, the 1TB drive is #1 on the Boot List. However, when I start up the computer, it boots to the 512GB drive.

I tried to fix the BCD by going into Settings > Update & Security > Recovery and clicking 'Restart now' under 'Advanced startup'. Once the computer restarted, I went Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command Prompt. In command prompt, I typed `bootrec /RebuildBcd`. When this command ran, it found the installation of Windows 10 on the 1TB drive and asked if I wanted to add it. I said yes, but it responded with `The system cannot find the file specified`.

The 512GB drive came with Windows 10 preinstalled, so I do not have any installation media.

How can I boot from the 1TB SSD?

Comment: I think that the easiest way to check if the new SSD is able to boot, is to disconnect the old one. If the drive boots correctly you will be able to see if Windows is activated. If something doesn't work, you will connect the old drive again. If you want to repeat the cloning, you can use this [guide](https://www.backup-utility.com/help/)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by using the free version of EasyBCD.

Install EasyBCD Community Edition. Start up the program and you should see a tab on the left that says 'Add New Entry'. Click it, and you should see a section labeled 'Operating Systems'. There, in the dropdown labeled 'Type', choose Windows Vista/7/8/10; type whatever name you want in the 'Name' box (use something unique for now, you can always change it later); in the 'Drive' dropdown, choose the letter of the drive you want to boot to and then click the green plus sign to add that entry.

Now click the tab on the left labeled 'Edit Boot Menu'. You should see all the boot options including the one you just added. Click the check box next to the new one to set it as the default and restart your computer. When it boots back up, you should be prompted to choose which operating system you want to use; use the arrow keys to find the one you just added and hit enter. It should boot to the new drive.